# How to make an iphone app start automatically after an upgrade?

Tags: iphone, background

Our app has voip background mode.

Suppose the app is running in the background and an update of the app is presented in appstore. The user goes to appstore and clicks "update" or "update all".

If the user now does not wait for the update to finish, and then explicitly starts the app, the app is no longer running in the background, and the user cannot receive incoming voip calls. He just can receive incoming apple push messages.

Am I missing something?

Comment: An app is disabled while its update is pending. The use case called "does not wait for the update to finish, and then explicitly starts the app" isn't possible, unless I completely misunderstand what you're saying there.

Comment: 1. User is running voip app X. The app is running in the background using a longliving TCP connection to my servers
2. User sees in App Store that a new version of the voip app X is available.
3. User selects in App Store to upgrade the voip app X.
4. App X starts updating. This can take a few seconds to a minute..

If after step 4, the user does not start the app X at least once, the app is not running on his iPhone anymore, and he will not receive incoming voip calls or messages. Of course he can still receive Apple Push but that is not good enough since I need loud sounds and alarms

Comment: Yeah, I don't know any way to automate this. Probably needs instruction to the user in the upgrade notes that appear with the upgrade listing in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just push him a message? Cheezy, but it would get him to launch your app. The message can be something like "Thanks for upgrading, incoming calls now enabled."

Comment: Is it possible to detect that a user upgrades his app? I do not think we receive a callback of that